# Kerberos authentication expires after 24 hours

Tags: java, kerberos

I try to use a timer to relogin but it doesn't work!

method register:

```
public static void register() throws IOException {
    LogUtils.fatal("Kerberos！");
    UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(kbsName, kbsPath);
    UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab();
    registerTime.getAndIncrement();
    LogUtils.fatal("success！");
}
```

timer:

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @SneakyThrows
            @Override
            public void run() {
                UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser();
                ugi.doAs((PrivilegedAction<Boolean>) ()->{
                    try {
                            KerberosUtils.register();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                            return true;
                });
            }
        };
```

LOG:

```
[FATAL] 2020-08-11 10:10:00,009 
Kerberos！

[FATAL] 2020-08-11 10:10:00,013 
success！
```

Exception Log:

```
failed authentication due to: An error: (java.security.PrivilegedActionException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]) occurred when evaluating SASL token received from the Kafka Broker. Kafka Client will go to AUTHENTICATION_FAILED state.
```

It runs the register method, I think. Because the log has been printed.
But it doesn't work!

Comment: **1.** Your logic is lame - `loginUserFromKeytab` is to be run on startup and `checkTGTAndReloginFromKeytab` is to be run periodically from a background thread (will relogin if TGT reached 80% of its lifetime or sthg like that)

Comment: **2.** Your logic is indeed lame - the _static_ `UserGroupInformation` object manages your default, implicit credentials, no need for `doAs()` >> if you really need to do impersonation then you must explicitly create and **store** an UGI object, which never will be "current"

Comment: It is indeed lame. Thanks for your comment.